Sed to find and replace a substring, then insert the full string
Example:
file contains the following:
lebnassvm0a-dr      test1      /vol/test1
lebnassvm0a-dr      test2      /test2
lebnassvm0a-dr      test3      /test3
stgtestsvm1-dr      test21      /test21
stgtestsvm1-dr      test22      /test22
stgtestsvm1-dr      test23      /test23

I want to find the "-dr" and replace with "-drt" and insert the full string in front of the existing, like this:
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test1      /vol/test1
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test2      /test2
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test3      /test3
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test21      /test21
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test22      /test22
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test23      /test23


Do you already know how to replace -dr with -drt?

Replacing the -dr with -drt is easy. the part i'm not sure about is inserting the replaced full string with the changed substring.

If you can ever have a first field that does not end with -dr then you should include that in your sample input/output so we can see how that should be handled.

What I would do:
$ sed -E 's/^([^-]+-dr)/\1t \1/' file
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test1      /vol/test1
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test2      /test2
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test3      /test3
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test21      /test21
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test22      /test22
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test23      /test23

The regular expression matches as follows:



Node
Explanation




^
the beginning of the string anchor


(
group and capture to \1:


[^-]+
any character except: - (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))


-dr
'-dr'


)
end of \1




Hi Gilles, Thanks! But i do not want the -dr-drt, just -drt..

\1t \1 as substitution should fix that

Fixed code accordingly

Thank you! I'll mark it as answered as soon as it will let me..

In this case \1, \0 and &  in the RHS  of the substitution command all represent the same string in the LHS.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed 's/^\S*-dr\>/&t &/' file

Replace the first non-white spaced string ending in -dr with itself followed by a t a space and the original string.

Using any awk:
$ awk '{print $1"t", $0}' file
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test1      /vol/test1
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test2      /test2
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test3      /test3
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test21      /test21
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test22      /test22
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test23      /test23

or GNU sed:
$ sed -E 's/\S+/&t &/' file
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test1      /vol/test1
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test2      /test2
lebnassvm0a-drt lebnassvm0a-dr      test3      /test3
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test21      /test21
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test22      /test22
stgtestsvm1-drt stgtestsvm1-dr      test23      /test23

The above assume given the example provided in the question that you really just want to duplicate and add t to the first field in the input, the requirement to match on -dr is a red herring.
